# Installing angularjs with NPM and NODEJS brings an error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I am having difficulties installing angularjs version 1.5.7 using npm. i have prepared my package.json file as follows.

```
{

 "name": "angular",
 "version": "1.5.7"

}
```

When i enter the following command in the terminal, where my project is located:

```
sudo npm install angular@1.5.7 --save
```

I encounter the following error message:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "angular@1.5.7" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install angular as a dependency of itself
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/nato/angular/npm-debug.log
```

This is my first time installing angularjs via npm so i don't Know what exactly i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your folder from `angular` to `angular-test` or something different than angular. Also, if you have a `package.json`, check that the package name is different from "angular".

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
npm ls
```

And see which modules are already installed. Sounds like you already have angular installed as a project's dependency or as another project's and you would not need that:

```
sudo npm install angular@1.5.7 --save
```

Note that each node module has it's own dependencies, it's own packages.json descriptor. So when you run 'npm install' it will look for those in node's module registry.

Also, try not installing dependencies with root permission/sudo unless you want to install that module globally like:

> sudo npm install -g gulp jshint

In this case makes sense to install gulp and jshint globally because it can be used by other project's in other directories. If not, avoid sudo, it can lead you to file permissions or scope issues. If you installed angular globally before, for another project, you should try uninstallig it first.